# PyMiniRacer adding Python classes to JS scope

Tags: javascript, python, scope

Using PyMiniRacer, I would be able to use Python objects in Javascript; using the PyV8 library:

```py
import PyV8

class Scope(PyV8.JsClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj1 = Object1()
        self.obj2 = Object2()

pythonScope = Scope()
context     = PyV8.JsContext(pythonScope)
context.enter()
context.eval(...)
```

And using this code, the javascript can access the properties of `Scope`: `obj1` and `obj2`

For PyMiniRacer, looking at the [code](https://github.com/sqreen/PyMiniRacer/blob/master/py_mini_racer/py_mini_racer.py), the `MiniRacer` class doesn't appear to accept any arguments into the constructor, so I don't see how I could add a Python Scope class into the JS scope. Is there a specific way of defining the class to be able to add a set of python classes to the JS scope, or do I need to inject them into the JS scope using a method I have missed while looking over the source code?

In the [Ruby RubyRacer](https://github.com/rubyjs/therubyracer), (I understand that the RubyRacer and PyMiniRacer are individual projects by different authors, although PyMiniRacer is inspired by RubyRacer) objects in the Ruby scope can be embedded by calling `context["funcName"] = funcName]`, but in Python...

```py
>>> from py_mini_racer import py_mini_racer
>>> context = py_mini_racer.MiniRacer()
>>> def helloWorld(num):
        return num * 2

>>> context["helloWorld"] = helloWorld
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
        context["helloWorld"] = helloWorld
TypeError: 'MiniRacer' object does not support item assignment
>>>
```

...it raises an error. I also tried `context.__dict__["helloWorld"] = "helloWorld"`, and running `context.eval(helloWorld(5))` returns a `ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined` error. All it does is allow me to call `context.helloWorld(5)` which doesn't help in executing from JS.

How can I insert Python objects into the JS scope such that in the JS code, I can call and access the methods and attributes from the Python object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, PyMiniRacer does not support attaching Python objects or functions to a JavaScript Context so it is not possible to call Python code from the JavaScript code.

Comment: OK thank you. Do you know any other V8 based JS interpreters for Python that are actively maintained and support embedding python objects? Thx.

Comment: Take a look at [V8Py](https://github.com/tbodt/v8py)